# How to duplicate fields in document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to duplicate some fields inside documents.
In the case we have fields in `object`, I want to duplicate them outside and **vice versa**.
My MongoDB version is 4.2.12.

Here is my collection :

```js
{
    'id': '1',
    'object': {
        'a': 'OK',
        'b': ''
    }
},
{
    'id': '2',
    'a': '',
    'b': 'OK',
}
```

Here is what I want as a result :

```js
{
    'id': '1',
    'a': 'OK',
    'b': '',
    'object': {
        'a': 'OK',
        'b': ''
    }
},
{
    'id': '2',
    'a': '',
    'b': 'OK',
    'object': {
        'a': '',
        'b': 'OK'
    }
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try aggregation pipeline with `{$addFields: {object: "$$ROOT"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$addFields` to add new fields
- `$cond` with `$ifNull` to check if the field already exists or not

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "a": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$a", null ] },
          "then": "$a",
          "else": "$object.a"
        }
      },
      "b": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$b", null ] },
          "then": "$b",
          "else": "$object.b"
        }
      },
      "object": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$object", null ] },
          "then": "$object",
          "else": { a: "$a", b: "$b"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ATQ372WDL8g)

Comment: In the case of the first document, it works well. But not with the second one

Comment: Sorry, I just see vice-versa. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.